# Fetch a tree with Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Given a forest of trees in a Neo4j REST server, I`m trying to return a single tree given the root vertex.

Being each tree quite large, I need a de-duplicated list of all vertices and edges in order to be able to reconstruct the full tree on the client side.

I tried multiple combinations around `MATCH (r:root)-[*]->()` but they return any path starting from the root, thus with lots of duplicates:

```
MATCH p = (r:root)-[*]->(x)
RETURN nodes(p) AS Vertices, rels(p) AS Edges";
```

this returns each and every path as follows, repeating each node every time:

```
a->b
a->b->c
a->b->c->d
```

etc...

Instead, I need a result having

```
{
    Vertices: [a, b, c, d],
    Edges: [[a, b], [b, c], [c, d]]
}
```

I'm using Node.js with Seraph, if relevant, but I`m not strictly bound to that library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So first off, you might want to add a `WHERE` clause to make sure that your path is always ending with a leaf:

```
MATCH p = (r:root)-[*]->(x)
WHERE NOT(x-->())
RETURN nodes(p) AS Vertices, rels(p) AS Edges";
```

So secondly, if you want to get all of the nodes and relationships in one go, you may need to execute two queries:

```
MATCH p = (r:root)-[*]->(x)
WHERE NOT(x-->())
UNWIND nodes(p) AS Vertex
RETURN DISTINCT Vertex;

MATCH p = (r:root)-[*]->(x)
WHERE NOT(x-->())
UNWIND rels(p) AS Edge
RETURN DISTINCT startNode(Edge), endNode(Edge);
```

*Update (Michael)*

```
MATCH p = (r:root)-[*]->(x)
WHERE NOT(x-->())
UNWIND nodes(p) AS Vertex
WITH collect(DISTINCT Vertex) as nodes, p
UNWIND rels(p) AS Edge
RETURN nodes, collect(distinct Edge) as rels
```

*Update2 (Michael)*

I found an even more compact way

```
MATCH p = (:root)-[r*]->(x)
RETURN collect(DISTINCT id(x)) as nodes, [r in collect(distinct last(r)) | [id(startNode(r)),id(endNode(r))]] as rels
```

If you also want to include the root node, use `*0..`

Comment: You can also combine the two queries with a union, and you only need the second one because it also gives you all nodes :)

Comment: There are some errors in the query, WHERE NOT(x-->()) leads to extraneous input >. UNWIND nodes(p) AS Vertex leads to mismatched inputs unwind, nodes and AS. What shall be the correct query?